# Mysql экранирование

Tags: mysql, экранирование

Хочу сделать запрос. Суть в том, чтобы найти текст и заменить его на пустоту (удалить).
Как решить вопрос с кавычками? …возможно есть другой метод?

```
UPDATE `s_products`
SET `body`= REPLACE(`body`, 'style="font-family: 'times new roman', times; font-size: medium;"', '');
```

Comment: Ну так скажите в чем вопрос с кавычками. Экранирование сводится к замене одинарной кавычки на *слеш+кавычку* внутри строки. Если весь запрос пишется руками, делайте буквально \'times new roman\', а если подставляется значение из переменной, то используйте подготовленный запрос с плейсхолдерами или специальную  функцию экранирования, типа mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: все верно)) спасибо) я думал что двойные тоже мешают...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экранирование сводится к замене одинарной кавычки на слеш+кавычку внутри строки.

```
UPDATE `s_products`
SET `body`= REPLACE(`body`, 'style=\"font-family: \'times new roman\', times; font-size: medium;\"', '');
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п. И если вам привели ответ в комментариях, то имейте совесть вставлять в ответ не огрызок, а приведённый в нормальный вид ответ.